# how to change slider to right and left buttom

Tags: javascript, html, css

i use this slider:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TiltedContentSlideshow/

but,i want remove bottom buttons and I use the left and right keys.
How can I put this left and right buttons.

help me Please !!

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far, remember this is a site to help you fix issues and find a solution to your problem, not just give you an answer :)

Comment: see your source :
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TiltedContentSlideshow/TiltedContentSlideshow.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript will do it for you

```
function click(){
    if (event.keyCode == 37){ 
        document.getElementById('leftbutton').click() 
    }

    else if (event.keyCode == 39){ 
    document.getElementById('rightbutton').click()
    }
}
```